# Supervisor paid for my food, what's the proper way to express my appreciation?

Tags: relationships, culture, lunch

I'm doing an internship in one of the Canadian government organization. Recently my supervisor got promoted, so our division(6 people) went out to a fancy restaurant to celebrity his promotion. Everything was fine, when we are paying the bills, my supervisor told waitress he would like to pay everyone's beer and my food(I'm the only student in our division). Since I'm a relatively awkward person and English is not my mother tone, I didn't really know how to properly respond to my supervisor's generosity. So I just simply said thank you so much, [my supervisor's name].

Did I take it too lightly? Will my colleagues and supervisor think I was being ungrateful? What would be the most appropriate way to express my appreciation in this case?

Comment: It sounds like you did it very well.  You acknowledged the gesture, thanked him, and let it go.  To make more of it would (possibly) be embarrassing for him.

Comment: That's just fine. There is no hard rule for thanking someone. A simple "thank you" may suffice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Canada that would be an appropriate response.  In inviting you all out, he would have put a greater financial burden on you than the others since you make less than the others.  It was a kind, well thought out gesture but one made so that you are not inconvenienced.  You are not expected to make more of it, just remember their kindness in future dealings.